# Run a simple shell command

Tags: winapi

What is the best WinAPI function to use when you only want to run a simple shell command like `hg > test.txt`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To simply run a file, then [`ShellExecute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) are the best options.

As you want to redirect output to a file/run a shell command, it complicates things...

Output redirection is a feature of the command prompt, and as such, the command you want to run needs to be passed to `cmd.exe` (on NT/XP+) passing `/c` and your command as the parameters (either `ShellExecute` or `CreateProcess` will do).

```
cmd /c "ipconfig >c:\debug\blah.txt"
```

The best way however is to use `CreateProcess()` and create your own pipes to talk to the stdin and stdout of the program (This is all `cmd` does internally)

Comment: Oh, this has already been answered on the almost duplicate [followup question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018228/correctly-using-createprocess/7018258#7018258)...

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ShellExecute()`, but why not try `system()` first? I am not so sure that `ShellExecute()` can actually do piping or redirection. There is also `CreateProcess()`, but that requires a bit more work. `CreateProcess()` gives you the best control, though.

Comment: I tried using CreateProcess. I've a question: why does `CreateProcess(0, "notepad.exe test.txt", ...)` work but `CreateProcess(0, "hg > test.txt", ...)` does not?

Comment: CreateProcess doesn't handle redirection. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017680/run-a-simple-shell-command/7022711#7022711) for more details.

Comment: CreateProcess doesn't act like a command line, as he tried to use it, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of issuing commands: the Windows Shell way, and the command line way.

Windows Shell issues commands by executing *verbs* on files. Verbs are associated with file types in the registry. Examples of common verbs are *Open* and *Print*. The WinAPI to use for this is [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Windows Shell does not help you pipe the output of a process to a file. You can do it using [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), but it is [a little bit involved](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q190351/).

The command line way is to use the [system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz%28VS.80%29.aspx) function.

Comment: -1. Jonathan pointed out nothing relevant. The strange windows-verb-thing works with system(), too. Try `#include <cstdlib>
int main () {
    system ("bitmap.bmp");
}`, assuming a bitmap file named "bitmap.bmp". Maybe *you* can point out the benefit of ShellExecute over system in this case? (if there is, I would be the last one not to vote you up)

Comment: @phresnel, dude, this is not a contest. Paul asked about the WinAPI way of issuing commands and I explained it. As for your example, it does not even execute a verb. Verbs are registered for file types. For instance, the Word.Document.12 file type has associated verbs *Edit*, *New*, *OnenotePrintto*, *Open*, *OpenAsReadOnly*, *Print*, *Printto*, and *ViewProtected*.

Comment: Even though I am not your "dude", I must apologize. I confused verbs with the standard action ("double-click") associated with files; however, in _this_ case, I don't see how `system()` is worse than `ShellExecute`

Comment: It is not about being better or worse. Paul asked about issuing commands using WinAPI. WinAPI issues commands using verbs.

Comment: Though 45 minutes ago, you yourself considered `system` as a worse answer: `However, as Jonathan pointed out, this has some drawbacks`, so I was not the one starting to judge ;). After that edit, of course, my -1-justification vanishes. Sidenote: One coulr also consider `system` to be part of the OS-API.