# How to redirect in, out and err streams from process created with CreateProcess function?

Tags: c++, c, windows, process, stream

I've just learned a few things about Microsoft CreateProcess function but I still don't know how to redirect in, out and err streams to my own streams. For example if I create process like that:

```
...
comp_exec_args.success = CreateProcess(NULL, comp_exec_args.params, NULL, NULL, comp_exec_args.inherit_handle, 
                                       comp_exec_args.c_flags, NULL, comp_exec_args.root.c_str(), 
                                       &comp_exec_args.startup_info, &comp_exec_args.process_info) ;
...
```

then how can I create proc_in, proc_out and proc_err variable of type std::istream, std::ostream and std::ostream respectively that they will become in/out/err streams of the process ? To be more precise I can say that I don't want process streams to be connected to the default standard in, out and err streams but I want to hold them elsewhere.

Comment: You can't use C++ streams with the WIN32 functions, it's as simple as that.

Comment: Win32 is a pure C interface, you can't use C++-`streams`

Comment: So is there any other way to create a process with redirected streams ?

Comment: I think previous comments are inaccurate. I think it's possible (and relatively easy) to redirect standard streams across a `CreateProcess` call. Unfortunately, I don't remember how!

Comment: See the code supplied in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16256188/7925