# Print CMD output to .txt with C

Tags: c, windows

does anyone have an idea how to save a CMD output to a .txt with C? I would like to do a ping and tracert and then ask if the result should be saved. Should it be saved, the result should be saved in a .txt.

My code is like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main ()
{

    char Testprint1[100],Testprint2[100];

    sprintf(Testprint2, "ping 127.0.0.1");
    system(Testprint2);

    sprintf(Testprint2, "tracert 127.0.0.1");
    system(Testprint2);

    printf("\nDo you want to save the output? (y)Yes / (n)No: ");

    if (Answer=='j')
    {
    FILE *Test;
    Test = fopen("Test_Log.txt", "w");
    fprintf(Test, "Ping:\n%s\n\nTracert:\n%s\n",Testprint1,Testprint2);

        if(Pinglog == NULL) 
        {
        printf("Log could not be saved.\n");
            system("\n\npause\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Log has been saved.");
            fclose(Pinglog);
            system("cls");
        }
    }

    else if(Answer=='n')
    {
        system("cls");
        system("\n\npause\n");
    }
}
```

The txt includes:

Ping:
ping 127.0.0.1

Tracert:
tracert 127.0.0.1

It is plausible for me that only this comes out as a result, but I have no idea how I can change that and how I can save the CMD output e.g. in a variable and then save it in the .txt.

Comment: You can use `popen` for that

Comment: @jvx8ss the analogue in windows is [_popen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen?view=msvc-170) with an underscore

Comment: @jvx8ss Thank you for your time. Where do I need to use it? Beforde the CMD output or before? Could you give me a example in my case, please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example that reads the command `ping` and saves it to a buffer

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1000
#define CMDBUFSIZE 100

int main()
{
    char buf[BUFSIZE] = {0}; // Will hold cmd output
    char cmdbuf[CMDBUFSIZE]; // Used to format the cmd
    char *ip = "google.com";

    snprintf(cmdbuf, CMDBUFSIZE, "ping %s /n 1", ip);

    FILE *p = _popen(cmdbuf, "r");
    if (p == NULL) {
        puts("popen failed");
        return 1;
    }

    fread(buf, BUFSIZE - 1, 1, p);
    printf("%s", buf);

    _pclose(p); // Make sure to _pclose so that the cmd doesn't turn into a zombie process
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the code also works, but it cannot be changed in such a way that it also does exactly the same as my code. Anyway, I can't get it. When I try to ping with an individual address, it tells me there are too many arguments. The line where I tried to implement this looks like this ->  char pingAdr[100];    FILE *Test = _popen("ping %s",pingAdr, "r");

Comment: @SergejWozke You cant format the first argument of popen, you should `sprintf` first

Comment: @SergejWozke I will edit the code to show an example of how to format it correctly

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pretty unconventional, which should be a flag that the approach tends in a messy direction. You're using C for things that are normally scripted. I'm going to focus on the use of `ping.exe`.

The conventional approach in C would be to use APIs to accomplish your tasks (e.g. instead of `ping.exe`, call [`IcmpSendEcho`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/icmpapi/nf-icmpapi-icmpsendecho)).

Your code, on the other hand, is launching a series of external processes to do your tasks, and attempting to orchestrate them. That's something scripting languages are great at, and C is rather bad at.

While it's simple to just invoke `ping.exe`, the downside is you only get the control that `ping.exe` grants you. If you on the other hand use `IcmpSendEcho`, you have full control over the behavior and output.

It's possible however. `ping.exe` (et al) output to `stdout`, and scripting languages (.cmd, .sh) have natural methods of redirecting stdout. By default stdout goes to the console/shell window. You can redirect stdout by using `>` (e.g. `ping >output.txt`). You can also redirect stdout in your own application, however it's not as trivial as calling `system()`.

At very least you will need to use `CreateProcess`.

There are many related questions on SO, like [How do I redirect output to a file with CreateProcess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018228/how-do-i-redirect-output-to-a-file-with-createprocess)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I know there are a lot of better option to do this task, like powershell for example. But I try to learn C and for that I try to give myself tasks. I try to give myself tasks that I could theoretically use in my everyday work. So maybe you could give me an example to better unterstand what you mean. I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is, to save the output directly inside the CMD command

```
ping 127.0.0.1 > Test_Log.txt
```

This saves the output of `ping 127.0.0.1` to the file named `Test_Log.txt`
which is exactly what you want.