# How can I start a WSL-based Linux executable from within PHP on Windows and capture its stdout?

Tags: php, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a program that only works on Linux, and I have my development environment on Windows.

- When I run a WSL command from `cmd` in Windows it works as expected.

  - When I run `C:\wsl echo "foo"` in `cmd.exe` I get `foo` back via stdout.
- When I run the same command from within php via `exec` I don't get any stdout output and get an exit code `-1073740791` which I assume is an error.

---

Cmd.exe:

```
C:\wsl echo "foo"
foo
```

PHP:

```php
<?php
    $cmd = 'wsl echo "foo"';
    exec($cmd, $out, $code);
    dd($out, $code);
?>
// $out is []
// $code is -1073740791
```

Comment: Is your code running from the same context? For example, is your code not running **inside** WSL?

Comment: The PHP code is executed on Windows (I use WAMP)

Comment: This is a horrible, horrible idea. Why do you want to do this? Assuming you can even get it working reliably (w.r.t. user-accounts, authX, the host web-server loading profile data correctly, etc) you'll be opening yourself up to all kinds of vulnerabilities (using `exec` in PHP is a code-smell in itself).

Comment: I have a program that only works on Linux, and I have my development environment on Windows

Comment: @Acqua Okay, that's reasonable - I've updated your question title to be clearer.

Comment: So, you're saying that when you start a shell and run that `wsl ...` command, it works. If you put the above code into a proper PHP file and run `php filename.php` from the shell it doesn't?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The OP is using `dd` which is a Laravel function, which suggests they're running it from within a webserver instead of PHP's command-line mode. I think we should avoid mentioning PHP's command-line mode because that will behave differently to PHP running in webserver (especially w.r.t. permissions, etc).

Comment: Have you gone through this page? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting

Comment: You can use Laravel stuff via commandline, too. In any case, if it works via commandline or not is important. If it does, PHP is not the issue but rather the execution environment. If it doesn't, the execution environment is irrelevant. Answering these questions before even asking here is why a [mcve] is required.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt If I run `php foo.php` from cmd, it works. If I run `exec('php foo.php')` from my code, it does not work.

Comment: @Acqua That's not what Ulrich is asking you to do. Also, "it does not work" is not an adequate problem-statement. What happens if you run any other "normal" Win32 command-line program from `exec`, such as `whoami` (don't use a built-in like `echo`).

Comment: @Acqua It's possible your PHP environment is configured to do strange things with `exec` - so what happens when you do `$tail = exec( "whoami", $out, $code ); echo $tail; echo $out; echo $code;` and run that from your web-browser (with Apache-on-Windows)?

Comment: From cmd it returns `my-pc-name\my-username`. From my code it returns `nt authority\system` (this is without wsl; if I run the same with wsl, it returns -1073740791).

Comment: `whoami` cannot be run via `wsl` (as it's a Windows program, not a Linux program) so that's normal. Also, I suspect that because your PHP code is somehow running under `SYSTEM` (which is very inadvisable - why is your webserver running as `SYSTEM`?) that wsl won't run because (I suspect, I'm not a WSL expert) it needs user profile data to know how WSL should be configured.

Comment: `whoami` is also available on Ubuntu

Comment: SOLVED!: All I had to do was change in services.msc the services wampapache64 and wampmysqld64 to run as my user rather than Local System account

Comment: @Acqua I'm pleased to hear that worked for you - I'll admit that I chose `whoami` at random (as I just wanted _any_ Win32 command-line program to use as a test), so it's entirely coincidental that it revealed the problem was the wrong user-account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the underlying issue was that your systemwide Apache web-server service (`wampapache64`) was configured to run as `NT Authority\SYSTEM` (aka `Local System` or `LocalSystem`).

...and running anything like a web-server as `LocalSystem` **is a very, very bad idea** for other reasons, especially when it's running PHP code - a simple mistake in uploaded-file handling or a failure to correctly sanitize user input could potentially hose your entire computer, especially when it's a publicly-exposed web-server that a malicious attacker can connect to.

---

Anyway:

Apparently when a process is running as `SYSTEM` it cannot use Win32's `CreateProcess` to invoke `wsl` to then indirectly invoke a Linux program.

- [PHP's `exec` function is implemented](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/5b01c4863fe9e4bc2702b2bbf66d292d23001a18/ext/standard/exec.c#L114) like so:

  - The `exec` function wraps PHP's internal `VCWD_POPEN`.
  - [`VCWD_POPEN` is a macro](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/01b3fc03c30c6cb85038250bb5640be3a09c6a32/Zend/zend_virtual_cwd.h#L273) defined as `#define VCWD_POPEN(command, type) virtual_popen(command, type)`
  - `virtual_popen` varies based on OS:

    - On Win32, `virtual_popen` simply invokes `popen_ex(command, type, CWDG(cwd).cwd, NULL)`.

      - [And `popen_ex` calls `CreateProcessAsUserW` or `CreateProcessW`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/7c2381e5eed05789d52785536e1fa37822e9c3d2/TSRM/tsrm_win32.c#L561) to actually start the new process.
      - I note that `popen_ex` uses `OpenThreadToken` to ensure the new process is created with the same user-account and permissions as the parent process - in this case `NT Authority\SYSTEM`.
- So PHP's `exec()` is *not* just a simple wrapper over C's `system()`.
- Whereas if `exec()` *was* a wrapper over `system()` then programs [would be invoked via `cmd.exe`](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939534/whats-a-win32-api-equivalent-of-the-stdlib-system-function) which will behave differently (though that too would likely fail as well)
- **[And WSL does not support running under Local System](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4803)**.

So by changing your web-server to run as a *real user account* that meant that the `CreateProcess...` call invoked `wsl` within a supported environment.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing Dai's answer;

You are probably running Apache as NT Authority\SYSTEM (aka Local System or LocalSystem), and WSL doesn't like to run as anything but your user (And its also a bad security practice)

A simple fix, at least for WSL's issues, is to change the service's properties to use your windows user, on `services.msc`, `wampstackApache` (or similar), `log on`.

`echo shell_exec("whoami");` will then report your user correctly and WSL will run just fine.

Disclaimer; I dont know how bad of a security issue this is, but it sounds kinda bad