# ShellExecute() not working with .bat file

Tags: c++, winapi

I trying to execute following bat file in c++ using win32 api.Following is code for execution.

```
  //#include "Shellapi.h"
    #include "Windows.h"
    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        ShellExecute(GetDesktopWindow(), "sa.bat","", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        DWORD LastError = GetLastError();
        return 0;
    }
```

but it is not working.

following is content "sa.bat"

**C:\windows\system32\wusa /uninstall /kb:2718695 /quiet /forcerestart**

but last error returns 1155.

Comment: Compare your arguments: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You fumbled the arguments, "sa.bat" should be passed as the **third** argument.

Comment: @HansPassant No its not :-(.I thing so some thing wrong with batch command.Did you thing so??Please my new question.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
//#include "Shellapi.h"
#include "Windows.h"
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  HINSTANCE hReturnCode=ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("cmd.exe"), _T("/C sa.bat"), NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
  DWORD LastError = GetLastError();
  return 0;
}
```

[EDITED]
This working suggestion is from Chris:

```
    //#include "Shellapi.h"
    #include "Windows.h"
    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
      HINSTANCE hReturnCode=ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("sa.bat"), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
      DWORD LastError = GetLastError();
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The batch file should work as the third argument, shouldn't it? I've used them in place of executables in other places.

Comment: Well, I just tested it, and it does run my batch file without routing through cmd.

Comment: In this case I would post your suggestion as an answer - my upvote have you already :)

Comment: It's already part of your answer. All I was hinting towards was needing "open" and moving the batch file to the next argument. Both of these ways worked when I tested them.

Answer (score 4):

`.BAT` files are not executable binaries, so batch file alone does not take off, instead it is started with command interpreter (CMD.EXE). On `ShellExecute` you either start it with `CMD /C` directly, or you leverage registry assotiation which starts `.BAT` file with an "open" verb.

See:

- [Run a simple shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7022711/868014)
- [How do you pass parameters containing spaces in vbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414496/how-do-you-pass-parameters-containing-spaces-in-vbs)

You apparently don't attempt to start CMD.EXE, so the association.

The error code you get is `ERROR_NO_ASSOCIATION` "No application is associated with the specified file for this operation." and it refers to `ShellExecute` API, not to the contents of your batch file.

> SE_ERR_NOASSOC
>
> There is no application associated with the given file name extension. This error will also be returned if you attempt to print a file that is not printable.

This means that `ShellExecute` could not figure out your arguments. The file should go third, not second, and then second argument would be "open" or NULL (verb). Applying the verb onto `.BAT` file would make the `.BAT` file "run".

Comment: .bat files may not themselves be binary executables, but they are directly executable via ShellExecute/Ex() since they are associated with cmd.exe in the Registry. Both articles you link to are using cmd.exe because they utilize extra functionality that requires it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I clarified that.

Answer (score 2):

This will also work:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   STARTUPINFO si;
   PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

   ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
   si.cb = sizeof(si);
   ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
   if( !CreateProcess( NULL, "cmd /C  sa.bat", NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)  )
   {
     printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d)\n", GetLastError() );
     return FALSE;
   }
   WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
   CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
   CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ShellExecute()` reports errors via its own return value, not via `GetLastError()`.  You also need to pass the filename in the `lpFile` parameter, not the `lpOperation` parameter.

Try this:

```
//#include "Shellapi.h"
#include "Windows.h"
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int nErrorCode = (int) ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, "sa.bat", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    if (nErrorCode <= 32)
      // an error occurred...
    return 0;
}
```