# ShellExecute bat file elevated (FMX, Win32)

Tags: winapi, firemonkey, c++builder

I want to spawn a batch file from my FMX app (on Win32) with elevated privileges.  From Remy's answer at the bottom [of this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621911/shellexecute-not-working-with-bat-file) on ShellExecute I found how to launch the batch file.  Now, i can't figure out how to launch it with elevated privilege. Below is my code:

```
String Prog = "c:\\Users\\rwp\\Desktop\\test.bat";
int nErrorCode = (int) ShellExecute(NULL, L"runas", Prog.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
if (nErrorCode <= 32) {
 ShowMessage("an error occured");
}
```

I added "runas" for the second argument after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586139/how-to-run-application-which-requires-admin-rights-from-one-that-doesnt-have-th) to no avail.  Running the batch file manually (right-click and run as admin) works.  Here is content of the batch file fyi (just kicks of a system imaging):

```
c:\Windows\system32\wbAdmin.exe start backup -backupTarget:D: -include:C: -allCritical -quiet
```

How can i ShellExecute this batch file as admin?

UPDATE 1:  I'm attempting to use CreateProcess per Remy suggestion.  Here is my code  (based on [this example](https://community.embarcadero.com/article/technical-articles/162-programming/15091-cbuilder-winexec-and-createprocess)):

```
//Code is inside a __fastcall button click
    PROCESS_INFORMATION     piProcInfo;
    STARTUPINFO             siStartInfo;
    siStartInfo.cb          = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    siStartInfo.lpReserved  = NULL;
    siStartInfo.lpReserved2 = NULL;
    siStartInfo.cbReserved2 = 0;
    siStartInfo.lpDesktop   = NULL;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags     = 0;

   //   String strCmdLine = "C:\\Users\\rwpatter\\Desktop\\test.bat";
    String strCmdLine = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wbAdmin.exe start backup -backupTarget:T: -include:C: -allCritical -quiet";

    // Create the child process.
    int rtrn =  CreateProcess(

        NULL,
        strCmdLine.c_str(),
        NULL,           // process security attributes
        NULL,           // primary thread security attributes
        0,              // handles are inherited
        0,              // creation flags
        0,              // use parent's environment
        0,           // use parent's current directory
        &siStartInfo,   // STARTUPINFO pointer
        &piProcInfo);   // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION

        // Wait for the processs to finish
        DWORD rc = WaitForSingleObject(
                      piProcInfo.hProcess, // process handle
                      INFINITE);
        ShowMessage(IntToStr(rtrn));
```

If I run it as shown (right-click on exe and run as admin) it returns 0 which means it [failed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa).  If I run it by putting the wbAdmin command line in the test.bat file (see commented line right above `String strCmdLine` in the code) then CreateProcess returns a 1 (success) but wbAdmin is still not running.  It flashed a DOS window and i captured it as shown in the picture below. It shows oriental characters in the title bar and says not recognized as internal or external command. But, if i run that test.bat directly (elevated) it runs wbAdmin no problem.

Any ideas on what is wrong?  Besides me obviously being ignorant.   (p.s. i'll get to testing Golvind's answer on the ShellExecute after this...)

[image]

Comment: Since the `bat` consists of a single command, I would just use `CreateProcess()` to run `wbAdmin.exe` directly, and if it doesn't already run elevated by itself then make YOUR app run elevated before invoking that command.

Comment: Not a direct answer but you can take inspiration from there :  https://github.com/TurboPack/DOSCommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Running the batch file manually (right-click and run as admin) works.

Because you are running the 64-bit version of cmd when you start it manually.

> It shows oriental characters in the title bar and says not recognized
>   as internal or external command.

Because your application is 32-bit. A 32-bit application does not see the same System32 folder as 64-bit applications. You can access the 64-bit System32 folder in 32-bit applications with the virtual sysnative folder.

```
#include <shellapi.h>
...
    String strCmdLine = "wbAdmin.exe start backup -backupTarget:T: -include:C: -allCritical -quiet";
    int rtrn = CreateProcess(
        NULL,
        strCmdLine.c_str(),
        NULL,           // process security attributes
        NULL,           // primary thread security attributes
        0,              // handles are inherited
        0,              // creation flags
        0,              // use parent's environment
        0,           // use parent's current directory
        &siStartInfo,   // STARTUPINFO pointer
        &piProcInfo);   // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION
    if (!rtrn)
    {
        String newCmdLine = "c:\\windows\\sysnative\\wbAdmin.exe start backup -backupTarget:T: -include:C: -allCritical -quiet";
        rtrn = CreateProcess(
            NULL,
            newCmdLine.c_str(),
            NULL,           // process security attributes
            NULL,           // primary thread security attributes
            0,              // handles are inherited
            0,              // creation flags
            0,              // use parent's environment
            0,           // use parent's current directory
            &siStartInfo,   // STARTUPINFO pointer
            &piProcInfo);   // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION
    }
```

Or compile your application to 64-bit.

Comment: Compiling as 64-bit works - lets me launch test.bat file elevated and runs the wbAdmin.  Using your other approach (with c:\\windows\\sysnative path) results in a KERNELLBASE.dll violation.  Never heard of that sysnative folder and can't find it.  Thank you.

Comment: sysnative  is a virtual folder, so you can't find it.It is only a redirection mechanism provided by 64-bit Windows system. 64-bit Windows redirects it to the real System 32 folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to launch CMD.exe as Administrator with `"runas"`, and specify the batch file as a "run-me-then-exit" (i.e. `/c`) argument to command prompt, as so:

```
WCHAR wszCmdPath[MAX_PATH];
GetEnvironmentVariableW(L"ComSpec", wszCmdPath, MAX_PATH);
ShellExecuteW(NULL, L"runas", wszCmdPath, L"/c \"C:\\Path\\BatchFile.bat\"", L"", SW_SHOW);
```

Both functions called here can fail, and robust code would test for success before proceeding.

Comment: Don't see why you could let the shell work out how to open a bat file

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I believe that if you just use the path to the batch file as the command in `ShellExecute`, it will not request elevation regardless of the `runas` verb

Comment: Thanks Govind.  This did not work, same result as the CreateProcess attempt i made (see UPDATE 1 above).  I can right-click and run the test.bat file as admin and it works correctly (starts wbAdmin and begins creating a system image).  Your code above doesn't work.  If i replace the wbAdmin line with just "notepad.exe" it opens notepad and keeps CMD open until i close notepad.  Looks like it doesn't like the elevation somehow.